# Soma Linhas PL SQL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, porcentagem, soma

Galerinha, criei um código que organiza todas as tarefas da empresa por setor. O objetivo deste código é identificar qual a porcentagem de atividades atrasadas por setor. O resultado foi o esperado.

[image: IMG1]

Agora eu agrupei e contei as tarefas distintas.
[image: IMG 2]

Queria saber como realizar o calculo de porcentagem para cada Setor.
Já tentei oq lembrei, mas estou sem ideias.

Seria a soma total das colunas meu 100%
E para os setores seria total do setor / total das colunas.

---

Tentei algo do tipo:

```
select 


sum(COUNT(DISTINCTTASK_SEQ)),
SUM(SETOR = 'CALDEIRARIA')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS CALDEIRARIA,
SUM(SETOR = 'ELETRICA')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS ELETRICA,
SUM(SETOR = 'INSPECAO')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS INSPECAO,
SUM(SETOR = 'INSTRUMENTACAO')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS INSTRUMENTACAO,
SUM(SETOR = 'MECANICA')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS MECANICA,
SUM(SETOR = 'OPERACAO')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS OPERACAO,
SUM(SETOR = 'OUTROS')/(SUM(CONTAGEM)) AS OUTROS,

from petro_backlog_equipestotal
group by SETOR
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Leia sobre analytic functions , principalmente a cláusula OVER. https://www.orafaq.com/node/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função RATIO_TO_REPORT é nativa do Oracle, e tem como objetivo mostrar a proporção de determinada quantidade em Relação ao Total.

```
SELECT NOME_SETOR, 
       ROUND( ( (RATIO_TO_REPORT(QTDE) OVER())*100 ) ,2 ) 
  FROM (
          SELECT NOME_SETOR SETOR, COUNT(*) QTDE    
            FROM TAREFAS 
          GROUP BY NOME_SETOR
       )
```

Comment: Esta não conhecia , quebra um senhor galho !

Comment: Opa! porém eu não tenho colunas para cada setor. Ta tudo em duas colunas apenas! É nelas que preciso realizar a operação. O código que tentei acima não funciona.

Comment: Preciso ver o sua linha do select completa.

Comment: Busquei mais informações sobre o comando dito e a maneira que informou, foi graças a isso que consegui. 100% útil, obrigado. O código final, ficou assim: 

``select

EQUIPE,
COUNT(TAREFA) AS TAREFA,
ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER()*100, 2) AS PORCENTAGEM

from petro_backlog_equipestotal
GROUP BY EQUIPE;``